# Process Builder Scheduled Action - Do Criteria Still Apply?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-job

I have a field in my Account object which I want all users to fill in. It can't be required because they won't necessarily have the information when creating the Account. I would like to remind the user to fill in the field after creating the Account if they have not filled it in.

What would be the best way to do this ? I was considering having Process Builder kick off a scheduled email alert action a week after creation of a new Account if the field is blank. The email would notify the user to either complete or delete the new Account.

My question is will the scheduled action re-evaluate the record to see if the field is still blank when the week comes around before sending out the email ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The criteria will still apply, as long as the process evaluates both insert and update. See [How Does Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> **What Happens When the Field Values Change?**
>
> - For processes that start when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for the record from the queue.
> - For processes that start when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record with that process. Scheduled actions remain in the queue, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria when the scheduled actions are executed.
> - If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with the field.
>
>   For example, a process is configured to email an opportunity owner 7 days before the opportunity close date. The close date is set to 2/20/2014. Salesforce processes the schedule on 2/13/2014 and sends the email. If the close date is later updated to 2/10/2014 and the schedule hasn’t been processed yet, Salesforce recalculates the schedule and sends the email on 2/3/2014. If Salesforce recalculates the schedule to a date in the past, it executes the associated actions shortly after you save the record.
> - If the record or object that the schedule is associated with is deleted, Salesforce never processes the schedule.

Comment: `If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with the field.` <- my experience with PB is different. The action will execute at the initially set date, no matter if the referenced date/time field is updated afterwards.

Comment: I believe I tested it at the time I posted this answer, and I know I have tested it with WFR. If you have observed contrary results it would be worth posting MVR here. @smukov

Comment: It could be a `date/time` thing: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252394/update-datetime-field-for-scheduled-action-in-process-builder-wont-trigger-acti